# Putting table of contents in a page without other elements

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

I want to put the table of contents in a separate blank page where it will be alone without any other element. How can I achieve this?

Comment: `\clearpage` before and after `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: @ArTourter: Write up an short answer so this question can be considered *answered*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `\clearpage` is the mechanism in LaTeX to force content to be sent to the next page. In this case since you want to have the table of content on its own page, you need to call `\clearpage` before and after invoking `\tableofcontents`